Replacing short grass with multiple pink petals on one block
I know that there is a command for replacing short grass with pink petals:
/fill <x y z> <x y z> <pink_petals> replace <short_grass>

but with this command the short grass only be replaced by one pink petal (on one block) whereas I want the short grass be replaced by multiple pink petals on one block since more than one pink petal can be placed on a block, similarly to other blocks such as sea pickles and candles.
Is there any command for this problem?

You can define a block's blockstates when placing it using commands.
In Bedrock Edition, it looks something like this:
/fill <x y z> <x y z> minecraft:pink_petals[growth=3] replace minecraft:short_grass

This will place the maximum amount of flowers on the block.
You can see more about the blockstates of Pink Petals and fill command on the Minecraft Wiki.
